# Google custom search results published date

Tags: google-search, google-programmable-search-engine, google-api

The published date of the results can be displayed on Google search in a browser by using `&as_qdr=y15`. Example [Link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pala%20jewellers%20cannon%20park%20coventry&oq=pala%20jewellers%20cannon&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.9950j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&as_qdr=y15)

[image]

How to get this information from the Google Custom Search API?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=KEY&q=pala%20jewellers%20cannon%20park%20coventry
```